# How to generate eaually probable random integer from another random integer distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_n, n\in \Bbb N$ be the random integer distribution with $$P(X_n=i)=1/n\cdot I(i\in[0, n)\cap \Bbb Z).$$

Question: in general, how to generate $X_n$ from $X_m$ when $m\ne n$?

Example: how to get $X_7$ out of $X_5$? Apparently one sample isn't sufficient because the state space has 5 states which cannot be divided into 7 equally sized subsets. My first thought would be to generate a state space whose size is a multiple of 7 via multiple iid samples of $X_5$. But it seems $5^k$ is never divisible by $7$. So even worse, we can never get it using only finitely many samples. We must design a kind of "hit some condition then stop" experiment to generate an infinite state space. So here's my shot: run $X_5$ twice and record the ordered pair $(i,j)$. That makes 25 outcomes. Impose an ordering on these 25 pairs. Now, if the outcome belongs in the first 4 pairs, discard them and the procedure starts over. If not, then note that the remaining 21 pairs can be divided into 7 equally probable subsets.

Is there any other perhaps more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Discarding and starting again may lose useful information.  If instead you threw a third die in such a case, you would have $4 \times 5$ cases and $14$ of them would be directly useful.  If not, throw a fourth die with $6 \times 5$ cases of which $28$ are useful, and so on

Answer (score 2):

Suppose, as a result of previously generated numbers, you are in one of $k$ equally-probable "states", where $1 \le k < n$  Take a new sample from $X_m$: now you are in one of $km$ equally-probable states, let's say state $z$ (in some previously determined ordering), where $0 \le z < k m$.  Let $km = q n + r$, $0 \le r < n$. If $z < q n$, return $\lfloor z/q \rfloor$.  Otherwise you are in one of $r$ equally-likely states, and the process continues.

Let $T(k)$ be the expected number of samples of $X_m$ used in this process starting with $k$ states.  Then
$$ T(k) = 1 + \frac{r}{km} T(r),\ r \equiv km \mod n $$

Thus with $m=5$ and $n=7$ we get
$$ \eqalign{T(1) &= 1 + \frac{5}{5} T(5)\cr
            T(5) &= 1 + \frac{4}{25} T(4)\cr
            T(4) &= 1 + \frac{6}{20} T(6)\cr
            T(6) &= 1 + \frac{2}{30} T(2)\cr
            T(2) &= 1 + \frac{3}{10} T(3)\cr
            T(3) &= 1 + \frac{1}{15} T(1)\cr}$$
and solving these we find that the expected number of samples needed is $T(1) = 1115/504$.

Comment: The OP example: 2d5, assign 21 of the 25 possibilities. If you get one of the other 4, roll another d5. Assign 14 of the 20 possibilities. If you get one of the other 6, roll another d5. Assign 28 of the 30 possibilities. If you get one of the other 2, roll another d5. Assign 7 of the 10 possibilities. If you get one of the other 3, roll another d5. Assign 14 of the 15 possibilities. If you happened to get the 15th possibility (an extremely unlikely scenario), then it is now functionally equivalent to just start over.

Comment: @Ian nice one. This seems to make maximum use of the corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

The following procedure for $X_5$ and $X_7$ generalizes.

Write the fractions $i\over7$ as “decimals” in base $5$.

```
0/7=0.000...
1/7=0.032412033...
2/7=0.120324122...
3/7=0.203241203...
4/7=0.241203241...
5/7=0.324120324...
6/7=0.412032412...
```

Generate the digits of a base-5 “decimal” number $x$ by choosing repeatedly from $X_5$. If the number you generate is between $k\over7$ and $k+1\over7$, your value from $X_7$ is $k$. You don’t often need to generate many digits to determine between which two fractions the number $x$ lies.

For example, if you drew $\color{blue}3$, then $\color{blue}0$, $x=0.\color{blue}{30}...$, and you can be certain your result from $X_7$ is $4$, because $${4\over7}=0.241203241_5\dots < 0.\color{blue}{30}000_5\dots < 0.\color{blue}{30}444..._5 < 0.324120324_5\dots={5\over7}.$$

After $d$ draws ($5^d$ possibilities), there are at most $6$ different draw patterns that leave you unsure of your result, so you fail to have an answer after $d$ draws with probability at most $6\over{5^d}$. So $4$ draws would be enough more than $99$% of the time.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific why in base $5$ the probability to hit any of $[i/7, (i+1)/7)$ is equal?

Comment: @Vim This trick is really a more general idea called the probability integral transformation. the idea is to generate a number uniform on $(0,1)$ and then plug it into the so-called quantile function of the target distribution. For a discrete variable (not necessarily discretely uniform) this can be done exactly using a finite but in general not bounded amount of entropy, because it suffices to stop once $U$ is guaranteed to be in some interval on which the quantile function is constant. As for why this procedure generates uniform variates at all, I think that is somewhat obvious.

Comment: @Ian yes. A simple transformation $(a_1, a_2, ...)\mapsto \sum_i a_i/5^i\in [0, 1]$ makes it clearer.

Comment: @Ian as for the "probability integral transformation" method you mentioned, is it just the inverse transform method? But i cannot see an obvious connection between this and the base transform used in this answer.

Comment: @Vim Yes this is what I mean. The point here is that to roll a d7 it suffices to know which of the intervals $[i/7,(i+1)/7)$ a uniform variable is in. This method here is using d5 rolls to generate base 5 digits of a uniform variable, stopping once you can be certain that the result will be in a particular one of these intervals. For example, if you got a 1 and then a 3, then the uniform result you would get by generating infinitely many digits will be somewhere between 0.13 and 0.14 in the end (in base 5), so you can stop by returning 2.

Comment: @Vim: The intervals are the same length (measure), and generating a sequence $d_i$ of random digits between $0$ and $b-1$ for any integer $b>1$ is equivalent to choosing a number ($0.d_1d_2d_3\dots_b$) from the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. As Ian said, I think this is somewhat obvious, but if you don’t agree, I can try to sketch an argument.